# How to find the maximal x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I am trying to find the maximal y for $x\in(0,\inf)$, $y'(x)=2ln(\frac{y(x)}x)$, $y(4)=7$ so I tried to replace $z=ln(\frac{y(x)}x)$ and $z'=\frac{y'} y-\frac 1 t$ but I got something weird. What can I do?

Comment: What do you mean by maximal $y$?

Comment: @Moo I need to find y(x*)=x* so that y'=0